# Want to create a specific script for my Raspberry Pi to watch directory and do some actions

Tags: linux, bash, raspberry-pi, inotify

I am a complete newbie in writing scripts, I have just started a few days ago, and was already able to create simple scripts to find files, move them, delete them, etc...
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry Pi OS installed on it.
Now I want to create a better script, using "inotify" to monitor a specific directory and performs some actions if some specific files are found. Aaaaaand, I am a bit lost.

Here is what I have found and tested :

```
MONITORDIR="/my_dir"
inotifywait -m -r -e create --format '%w%f' "${MONITORDIR}" | while read NEWFILE
do
...
```

With this, I can generate an action whenever any new file appeared in my folder.

What I want :

1. If a new file with specific name (not the complete name, but just a part of the name of the file) with a specific .pdf extension is detected in the directory,
2. Then, move this file in another directory
3. And send an email using postfix, including the name of this new file, without the complete path of the file

Any help with this will be good for me, since I am a beginner, I know have a lot to learn, and I am sure I will.

Thank you !

Comment: Probably it's best to start writing *something*, and then find out why it does not work; if it does, you're done! For matching PDF files see the '%%' for parameter expansion, move should be trivial, and sending email using `mailx` for example is also easy to do.

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! I'm gonna keep digging with this